# HP ProLiant DL380 G5 Linux Install

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I would like to let you know up front I am very much a beginner here so please bear with me.

To start I purchased two HP ProLiant DL380 G5's for cheap because a company down the road went under.

Now I have them set up and they are both running Windows Server 2003.

I would like to inquire about the best way to begin by installing Linux, I would like to run a LAMP stack just to set up and play around with a web server environment. (I am very fond of Linux and use it regularly on the non server side of the coin. I am not just jumping in to Linux blindly)

I am a Web Developer currently and I want to set up my own experimental web server on the side to gain experience.

Is there a best way of doing this or just jump straight in to uploading the Linux server on to the HD.

What compatibility issues may I run into?

Thank you for being patient.

Comment: Jump straight in. You're not relying on the servers for anything, so just get to it.

Comment: OK Thank you. I wasn't to sure  if it would be detrimental to the server if I just wiped it a started anew.